# Python re.findall fails at UTF-8 while rest of script succeeds

Tags: python, regex, utf-8

I have this script that reads a large ammount of text files written in Swedish (frequently with the åäö letters). It prints everything just fine from the dictionary if I loop over `d` and `dictionary[]`. However, the regular expression (from the raw input with `u'.*'` added) fails at returning utf-8 properly.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from os import listdir 
import re
import codecs
import sys

print "Välkommen till SOU-sök!"
search_word = raw_input("Ange sökord: ")

dictionary = {}
for filename in listdir("20tal"):
    with open("20tal/" + filename) as currentfile:
        text = currentfile.read()
        dictionary[filename] = text

for d in dictionary:
    result = re.findall(search_word + u'.*', dictionary[d], re.UNICODE)
    if len(result) > 0:
        print "Filnament är:\n %s \noch sökresultatet är:\n %s" % (d, result)
```

Edit: The output is as follows:

If I input:

```
katt
```

I get the following output:

```
Filnament är: Betänkande och förslag angående vissa ekonomiska spörsmål   berörande enskilda järnvägar - SOU 1929:2.txt 

och sökresultatet är: 

['katter, r\xc3\xa4ntor m. m.', 'katter m- m., men exklusive r \xc3\xa4 nor m.', 'kattemedel subventionerar', av totalkostnaderna, ofta \xe2\x80\x94 med eller utan', 'kattas den nuvarande bilparkens kapitalv\xc3\xa4rde till 500 milj.
```

Here, the Filename `d` is printed correctly but not the result of the `re.findall`

Comment: What do you mean `fails at returning utf-8`. Does it throw an error or just fails to find a match?

Comment: Can you add an sample input and show that What's your output?

Comment: Please edit that into your question instead. Comments don't format well enough for that kind of thing.

Comment: Are you talking about the repr output in the list?

Comment: Yes, the output is the value of  `dictionary[d]`, which is where the regular expression is looking around.

Comment: result gives the correct output no? Did you iterate over the list and print the words?

Comment: Your list contains `katter, räntor m. m.
katter m- m., men exklusive r ä nor m.
kattemedel subventionerar
av totalkostnaderna, ofta — med eller utan
kattas den nuvarande bilparkens kapitalvärde till 500 milj` What should it be?

Comment: Padriac: Yes, that is the correct output.

Comment: You get the same when you loop over and print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python `2.x` unicode list items normally output escaped unless you loop through each or join them; maybe try something such as this:

```
result = ', '.join(result)

if len(result) > 0:
    print ( u"Filnament är:\n %s \noch sökresultatet är:\n %s" % (d, result.decode('utf-8')))
```

**Input**:

```
katt
```

**Result**:

```
katter, räntor m. m. katter m- m., men exklusive r ä nor m. kattemedel subventionerar av totalkostnaderna, ofta — med eller utan kattas den nuvarande bilparkens kapitalvärde till 500 milj
```

Comment: YES! That worked! The output is now printing out my åäö like a charm. Thank you very much! (and everybody else ofc.)

Answer (score 0):

The way file names are [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) is file system and OS dependent . Your particular regex may not match the normalization method correctly. Hence, consider this solution by [remram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711380/remram):

```
import fnmatch
def myglob(pattern, directory=u'.'):
    pattern = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', pattern)
    results = []
    enc = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
    for name in os.listdir(directory):
        if isinstance(name, bytes):
            try:
                name = name.decode(enc)
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                # Filenames that are not proper unicode won't match any pattern
                continue
        if fnmatch.filter([unicodedata.normalize('NFC', name)], pattern):
            results.append(name)
    return results
```

I faced a similar problem here: [Filesystem independent way of using glob.glob and regular expressions with unicode filenames in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903338/filesystem-independent-way-of-using-glob-glob-and-regular-expressions-with-unico)