# TensorFlow: use gfile.FastGfile() method can't not read a file with its path include Chinese characters

Tags: unicode, tensorflow

I want to read use `gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()` to read a picture and use it as the input of my project, and I use the directory name as the lable of these pictures which are include in the directory, when the directory name is in English, my code works fine, but when the directory name is in Chinese, it throws this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/pythonWS/imageFilter/jpegFileJudge.py", line 27, in <module>
    image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
    packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 106, in read
    self._preread_check()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
    packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 73, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
    packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in 
    raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile 
    failed to Create/Open: F:\vsWorkspace\pics\test\三宝鸟
    \0ff41bd5ad6eddc403fa02d13bdbb6fd526633fe.jpg : 
    ϵͳ\udcd5Ҳ\udcbb\udcb5\udcbdָ\udcb6\udca8\udcb5\udcc4\udcceļ\udcfe\udca1\udca3
```

my test code is :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import glob
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
image_folder='F:/vsWorkspace/pics/test'
os.chdir(image_folder)
count=0
for each in os.listdir(image_folder):
    each=os.path.abspath(each)
    os.chdir(each)
    for image_path in os.listdir(each):
        image_path = os.path.abspath(image_path)
        print(image_path)
        image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
        count += 1
os.chdir(image_folder)
```

My envirorment is Windows7 x64, python 3.5.3 and TensorFlow 1.0, How can I solve this problem?

By the way,I have to use Chinese directories' name use my pictures lables.

Comment: I am able to read a file with the same path with unicode characters in Linux with Tensorflow 1.0.1. The issue could be that Python Normalizes Unicode in a way which the underlying OS (i.e. Windows) is not happy with: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29903338/987185 Perhaps you can work around the problem by using relative paths inside the second `for` loop instead of absolute paths?

Comment: @musically_ut thanks a lot, that's amazing! It works fine after I change the inside 'for' loop use relative path for the 'gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()' function, but I think sometimes it is not convenience just use relative paths, such as when I want use the path as a parameter, I combine the whole path in a function and read the file in another function, of course we can use 'os.path.chdir()' to keep the  '.'  path always be the directory where the file is, but that make the code very terrible, do you think so?

Comment: Yes, using relative paths is, at best, a workaround. I'd personally pick my battles unless this was production critical code and imperative that it worked with arbitrary filenames. If you want to really fix the code, though, you can consider figuring out the normalization being used by your OS (http://qerub.se/filenames-and-unicode-normalization-forms) and then explicitly normalize the `image_path` as done in the answer to the question I linked to previously before passing it to `gfile.FastGFile`.

Comment: @musically_ut ok，I will  try it. Thank you a lot for your help.